# Can a JavaScript function rename itself?

Tags: javascript

I realize a function can be copied to a new variable very easily by writing:

```
var wu = function() {
   // do stuff
)

var tang = wu;
var bee = tang;
// etc
```

and in this way can go by a theoretically infinite number of names. I also realize that in the above example, I could then say `var wu = undefined` and the reference would be removed, but I’m wondering if a function can **rename itself** as part of its own context? Meaning, can I write:

```
function wuTang() {
   // do stuff
   // rename self
}

wuTang(); // runs successfully
wuTang(); // returns undefined
```

I’m not worried about the process of creating a new name, I’m simply wondering if this is possible. I do not want to call a second function to rename the original function, I want the function to rename itself so it can only be invoked by a given name one time.

Comment: Sure, put `wuTang = undefined;` in the function body?

Comment: "*so it can only be invoked by a given name one time*" - notice that whoever your caller is, he could always save a reference to the function before calling it.

Comment: @Bergi Ok I can remove a variable's reference to a function, but I can't do that in my second example above

Comment: Yes you can. (Have you tried it?) `function wuTang() {}` just creates a variable `wuTang` that references a function.

Answer (score 3):

```
window.wutang = function() {
  var f = window.wutang;
  window.watang = f;
  delete window.wutang;
}
```

That should be sufficient to “rename” itself :)

```
wutang(); // ok
wutang(); // fail
watang(); // should kill self :)
```

Comment: No need to make it a `window` property.

Answer (score 2):

Yes, it is possible. To rename a function, you need to add a new name to it, and then remove its old name. Example:

```
 function wuTang() {
        newWuTang = wuTang; // Add new name (reference) to the function
        wuTang = undefined; // Remove old name (reference)
 }
```

In this case, note the absence of keyword (var,let,const,...) in front of `newWuTang` is what you want, because according to w3:

> If you declare a variable, without using "var", the variable always
> becomes GLOBAL.

This function will run one time only as `wuTang`, and will rename itself as `newWuTang`.

I once used something similar with some `eval` in my function so I could pass the new wanted name as an argument to the function. But you know what they say about `eval`... I must have felt pretty wild that day!